# Udev (197) last_rule not working

Tags: udev

I am using udev version 197. I write a rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/00-test.rules`
It's content is :

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="e0",
>   ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
>
> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",
>   ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="e0", ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="01",
>   OPTIONS+="last_rule"

According to udev manual, `last_rule` means no other rule will execute for the underlying subsystem or device

But problem here is that, later rule is getting executed.

How am I supposed to debug it ?

But the problem here is that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

udev hasn't supported the "last_rule" option since version 147.

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/udev/ChangeLog#1509

Comment: Ohh !! I wasn't aware of that.

If the said option is not available in Udev since 148 version, how can I achieve the same goal then ?

Comment: You can use `GOTO` and `LABEL` to achieve something similar. `GOTO` and `LABEL` doesn't work across files, so the best you could do it to have a `LABEL` at the end of your rules file and replace all the `OPTIONS+="last_rule"` with `GOTO="end_of_file"`.

Instead of being the last rule, this will make it the last rule executed within this file. Rules in other files can be executed after yours.